# Adding own annotation to dynamic skip test in TestNG

Tags: java, testng

I would like to provide elegant mechanism to skip chosen tests when value of some environmental variable is not admissible. I chose adding my own annotation `@RunCondition` to define which value are allowed for particular tests. Then I created my own listener for TestNG that marks tests as disabled when value of environmental variable is not within admissible scope defined in annotation parameters.

My code looks as follows:

```
public class ExampleTest {

    private int envVar;

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() {
        //set up of some environmental variables which depends on external source
        StaticContext.setVar(getValueFromOuterSpace());
    }

    @RunCondition(envVar=2)
    @Test
    public void testFoo(){

    }
}


public class SkipTestTransformer implements IAnnotationTransformer {
    @Override
    public void transform(ITestAnnotation iTestAnnotation, Class aClass, Constructor constructor, Method method) {
        RunCondition annotation = method.getAnnotation(RunCondition.class);
        int[] admissibleValues = annotation.envVar();
        for (int val : admissibleValues) {
            if (StaticContext.getVar() == val) {
                return; // if environmental variable matches one of admissible values then do not skip
            }
        }
        iTestAnnotation.setEnabled(false);
    }
}

public @interface RunCondition {
    int[] envVar();
}
```

My code works great, but there is a small problem that `transform` method is invoked before the `setUp` which is the `@BeforeClass` function. Is there any other possibility to run Transformer after all initialization of test? I consider such solution elegant and clear and I don't want any ugly if clauses to reach my goal...

I'm using Java 7 and TestNG v5.11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to implement IMethodInterceptor (*An instance of this class will be invoked right before TestNG starts invoking test methods.*) instead of annotation transformer. It will allow to manage list of tests which will be executed. It also allows to work with your tests annotations. The restriction is that test methods having dependencies will not be passed to intercept method.

Answer (score 1):

There is a **better concept directly supported by the testing frameworks** called **assumptions**. You should not disable the test, but rather skip the execution:

- in JUnit you can use `assumeThat(boolean)` family of methods
- in TestNG you can throw `SkipException`

In that case the method will not disappear, it will be marked as skipped.

Comment: But how am I supposed to throw `SkipException` when I am parsing an annotation? Your solution would work perfect when I would check condition of skipping in every test separately.

Comment: Ah, that was not clear from the description. So can you explain it a little bit more. What exactly do you expect out of it, add more tests to the example, ...

Comment: I would create a helper method `assumeThat(boolean)` that will be called in every method that now uses `@RunCondition`. And I would move the expression in the argument of `assumeThat()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can check your own annotation in a setup method (`@BeforeMethod`) and throw a `SkipException` to skip this test.

```
public class ExampleTest {

    private int envVar;

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() {
        //set up of some environmental variables which depends on external source
        StaticContext.setVar(2);
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void checkRunCondition(Method method) {
        RunCondition annotation = method.getAnnotation(RunCondition.class);
        if (annotation != null) {
            int[] admissibleValues = annotation.envVar();
            for (int val : admissibleValues) {
                if (StaticContext.getVar() == val) {
                    // if environmental variable matches one of admissible values then do not skip
                    throw new SkipException("skip because of RunCondition");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @RunCondition(envVar = 2)
    @Test
    public void testFoo() {

    }

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public @interface RunCondition {

        int[] envVar();
    }

}
```